# Java Annotations don't work with external Jar Files

Tags: java, file, jar, annotations, external

So, I'm currently working on a plugin system (plugins are jar files located in a plugins folder) for my command line "operating system". Works fine but the API doesn't.

I am using Annotations to get the Plugin main class and the event classes. However, it doesn't seem to find my Annotations.

This is what I use to load my plugins:

```
public static void loadPlugin(File file)
{
    try
    {
        URL urlList[] =
        { new File("plugins/" + file.getName()).toURI().toURL() };
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urlList);
        Class<?> pluginclass, eventclass = pluginclass = null;
        String name, version = name = null;
        Priority priority = Priority.NORMAL;

        String[] classes = Utils.getJarClasses(file, "plugin").toArray(new String[]
        {});

        for (String s : classes)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
            Class<?> c = classLoader.loadClass(s);
            Plugin p = c.getAnnotation(Plugin.class);
            EventHandler e = c.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class);

            if (p != null)
            {
                System.out.println("not null!");
                pluginclass = c;
                name = p.name();
                version = p.version();
                priority = p.priority();
            }

            if (e != null)
            {
                eventclass = c;
            }
        }

        switch (priority)
        {
        case NORMAL:
            plugins.add(new Class<?>[]
            { pluginclass, eventclass });
        case DEVELOPER_API:
            apis.add(new Class<?>[]
            { pluginclass, eventclass });
        }
        print("Loaded Plugin: " + name + " V" + version + " with priority " + priority.toString() + ".");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's printing out the class it's currently looping through just fine, but **p** and **e** are always null, no matter what. **version** and **name** are always null, too, obviously.

My Annotation classes have got `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`, that's the main reason why I'm asking here.

I have tested a similar system, just that one didn't use jar files (classes inside of a package, instead) and worked fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the JVM think your classes have _any_ annotations?  What does `c.getAnnotations()` tell you?  I wonder if it's a classloader issue, where the annotations are of type `Plugin`-loaded-by-CL1 and you're asking for annotations of type `Plugin`-loaded-by-CL2...

Comment: String: [plugin.Events, plugin.CommandPing, plugin.Pinger]
plugin.Events
[]
plugin.CommandPing
[]
plugin.Pinger
[] That's what it outputs with Arrays.toString, meaning, it contains nothing at all.

Comment: What does `Utils.getJarClasses(..)` do? Please at least show the code for that method by editing your question, ideally provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). then notify us by commenting here.

Answer (score 5):

One reason that could explain the described behavior is that you are *mixing* class loaders: an annotation will only be visible if both the annotation class and the annotated type are loaded by the same class loader. This has to do with the use of the Reflection API as the mechanism employed to actually perform the annotation lookup process.

In your code you are using a custom class loader, `classLoader`, to load the classes from an external jar file, but both the `Plugin` and `EventHandler` classes are loaded by the class loader running your `loadPlugin` method.

In order to solve the problem, I think you can provide the class loader which is running the `loadPlugin` method as a parent class loader of the custom one, something like:

```java
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urlList, YourClass.class.getClassLoader());
```

A similar behavior has been also formerly reported here, in stackoverflow. See, for instance, the accepted answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437443/is-the-defining-classloader-of-a-class-level-annotation-always-a-parent-of-the-i) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451498/cant-get-annotations-from-classes-loaded-by-custom-classloader-in-tomcat).

Comment: I am always sorry to see people making an effort writing general answers because the OP does not react to any questions (such as mine), thus not giving anyone a chance to write a concrete answer, leaving people to speculate or write good, but generic answers like yours, which was not even rewarded by a comment, not even to mention accepting the answer and giving you the full bounty. I want to pay respect to your effort. I would have written a similar, but more concrete answer but wanted to wait for the OP's reaction first. I am happy I did not waste my time on it.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex, I really appreciate your comment. I started answering questions on the site not long ago, but despite this fact, I found that sometimes it is a bit frustrating not to get feedback from the people you want to help. But hey, it shouldn't put us off. Thank you again

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful.

Comment: You are very welcome @Hodglem. I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful.