# Is the defining classloader of a class level annotation always a parent of the initiating classloader of that class?

Tags: java, classloader

Suppose the following:

```
@SomeAnnotation
public interface Foo {
}
```

I would like to know if it is always the case that either the defining classloader of `SomeAnnotation` is equal to or a parent of the initiating classloader of `Foo`.

I have read [JVMS v8 section 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3). but I'm not sure what applies here. Section 5.3.4 talks about loading constraints, but they seem not to apply for annotations.

The question I'm asking is because code like this:

```
    Class<?> fooClass = //will in some way obtain a reference to class Foo
    fooClass.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

will fail in the presence of different classloaders. I know I could use [getAnnotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotations--) and search in the resulting array for an element whose class name is equal to the name of `SomeAnnotation`. But I'm wondering if the following will work too:

```
    Class<?> fooClass = //will in some way obtain a reference to class Foo
    fooClass.getAnnotation((Class<? extends Annotation>) fooClass
            .getClassLoader().loadClass(SomeAnnotation.class.getName()));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer: no

The long answer.

`RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` annotations are available for discovery via the reflection API only. This is done to ensure loose coupling between annotations and annotated code. According to [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6322301), `getAnnotations()` must skip unknown annotations which implies that it's ok to have annotations that are not recognized by the classloader. The behavior of real Java code discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451498/cant-get-annotations-from-classes-loaded-by-custom-classloader-in-tomcat) validates that assumption.

This behavior has two implications:

1. All unrecognized annotations (e.g. the ones not in classpath) become "invisible"
2. In order to reveal them, the class must be completely reloaded by a different classloader that has access to both, the type and annotations.

For example if `somepkg.SomeAnnotation` was not in classpath when `someClass` was loaded, this will not work:

```
Class<?> someClass = ....
URL [] classPathWithAnnotations = ....

ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classPathWithAnnotations);
Annotation a = someClass.getAnnotation(cl.loadClass("somepkg.SomeAnnotation"));
// a will be null
```

But this will:

```
Class<?> someClass = ....
URL [] classPathWithSomeClassAndAnnotations = ....

ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classPathWithSomeClassAndAnnotations, null);
Annotation a = cl.loadClass(someClass.getName()).getAnnotation(cl.loadClass("somepkg.SomeAnnotation"));
```

Comment: Thanks for that well done answer. I was already part through your answer by myself when you published it. I had noticed that Oracle JVM uses an `AnnotationParser` when requesting annotations. So since annotations are loaded lazy there is no need to take extra care of them in JVMS or JLS.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to understand what was wrong in my case. Good explanation.