# How to reload a class so that a annotation becomes visible?

Tags: java, classloader

In a [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437443/is-the-defining-classloader-of-a-class-level-annotation-always-a-parent-of-the-i) I got to know that in order to really be sure that some annotation is present or not somewhere in a class I need to reload it with a classloader that has access to both - the annotation and the class.

Now I'm struggling with how such a classloader would work. In my setup I just have the annotation as a `java.lang.Class` instance and the class that might be annotated with that annotation also as a `java.lang.Class` instance. Both might be loaded by some different classloaders I don't know anything about (classes might be loaded remotely, so they are not on the local file system).

While searching I [found this JoinClassLoader](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/12.htm)

```
/**
* A class loader that combines multiple class loaders into one.<br>
* The classes loaded by this class loader are associated with this class loader,
* i.e. Class.getClassLoader() points to this class loader.
* <p>
* Author Christian d'Heureuse, Inventec Informatik AG, Zurich, Switzerland, www.source-code.biz<br>
* License: LGPL, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html<br>
* Please contact the author if you need another license.
*/
public class JoinClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

private ClassLoader[] delegateClassLoaders;

public JoinClassLoader (ClassLoader parent, ClassLoader... delegateClassLoaders) {
   super (parent);
   this.delegateClassLoaders = delegateClassLoaders; }

protected Class<?> findClass (String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
   // It would be easier to call the loadClass() methods of the delegateClassLoaders
   // here, but we have to load the class from the byte code ourselves, because we
   // need it to be associated with our class loader.
   String path = name.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
   URL url = findResource(path);
   if (url == null) {
      throw new ClassNotFoundException (name); }
   ByteBuffer byteCode;
   try {
      byteCode = loadResource(url); }
    catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ClassNotFoundException (name, e); }
   return defineClass(name, byteCode, null); }

    // some code omitted

} // end class JoinClassLoader
```

So my question is this:

Given a class instance of an arbitrary class `C` and a class instance of an annotation class `A` that may be loaded by arbitrary classloaders. A `JoinClassLoader` is instantiated with the classloaders of `C` and `A` in this order as delegating classloaders. Will that `JoinClassLoader` reload class `C` upon invoking `findClass` so that annotation `A` is always visible when `C` was actually annotated with it? If not how would such a classloader actually look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a question I asked earlier I got to know that in order to really be
>   sure that some annotation is present or not somewhere in a class I
>   need to reload it with a classloader that has access to both - the
>   annotation and the class.

Given a class that has already been loaded by a classloader which might not have had access to all the annotations, I can believe that to be true.  I think you've drawn the wrong conclusion, however.

If you want to be able to reflectively analyze a class's annotations at runtime, then the best solution is not to reload it.  Instead, you should ensure that it is loaded *in the first place* by a classloader that can also see the annotations of interest.  (And if that turns out not to be sufficient, then I don't see how you can expect reloading to help.)

In any case, reloading the class gives you a different class (of the same name), even if its bytecode is identical to that of the previously-loaded version.  It is tricky to use this for anything but reflective analysis, and it is very difficult to be certain that the two classes actually *do* have identical bytecode.  Reloading *certainly* does not replace the existing class with the newly-loaded one.  All manner of fun can ensue.