# When does the JVM load the annotation class

Tags: java, annotations, jvm, classloader

I found that if I use an annotation, the program will not throw a `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
class A {
        @Transactional
        public void insert() {
            //insert something
        }
    }
```

**Tomcat** starts successefully without the **javaee-api-7.0.jar** which contains the class `javax.transaction.Transactional`

It makes me very confused, shouldn't the JVM throw a
`ClassNotFoundException` when it loads the class `A`?

Comment: Are you sure Tomcat doesn't define its own `Transactional` annotation?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23502439/1466267

Comment: @DonyorM Yes,I'm sure.When I acctually get the annotation by reflection,it throws ClassNotFoundException

Comment: @SpaceTrucker it hepls me a lot,thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. Annotations are just metadata. It's expected that byte-code containing annotations runs fine even if the annotation is not in the classpath. Of course, if some library tries to actually access and use the annotation that is not in the classpath, that won't work.

This is explicitely supported in order to be able, for example

- to add annotations used by byte-code static analysis tools like FindBugs, that are in no use when running the code in production
- to be able to use detached JPA entities in a client even though the server is the only one to actually use the JPA annotations