# Why classes loaded with boot classloader (bootclasspath) doesn't include annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, bootclasspath

I was writing unit tests for my javaagent but faced with behavior of JVM I guess which I wasn't aware before and I curious if there is any explanation or article about it. I tried google it and search on SO but with no success.

I found that classes which are included into boot classpath doesn't have annotations with them. To demonstrate it I created a simple JUnit test

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
    }
}
```

It perfectly runs of course :) but if I configure eclipse project like this:[image]

Then it fails with java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods. I see in the debugger that code which checks annotations cannot find them.

Comment: Check you java class's build path once.If there is any unwanted jars, remove them and try to run.

Comment: Eclipse probably adds junit jar on classpath. I think, possible that since junit jar is not on boot classpath then during boot classloading java ignores the annotation as missing dependency. Can somebody confirm with a reference on some article or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on SO to my question which is perfectly explains what is going on (I voted up there).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502439/2013497

JUnit library is added by Eclipse and it goes to regular classpath whenever bootloaded classes doesn't have a way to reference them.